# Can you use the same Google FCM sender ID and server key across multiple apps?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

From a best practices standpoint, should you create a new Sender ID / Server Key per app/project that you want to incorporate FCM on?

I am using OneSignal to send Push Notifications to my apps, and I am setting up my Android use, and if I had multiple apps if there was any benefits/drawbacks to having them all under one project with the same Sender ID and using the same server keys?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can connect more than one app in one signal using one information (Sender ID / Server Key) from firebase ...